# Create multiple GitHub private repositories from a template

Tags: node.js, git, github, version-control

I have to programmatically create repositories on GitHub. Each of them will have the same initial commit. This is for hundreds of them.

I have found a command line [tool](https://github.com/kgryte/github-create-repo) to create repositories which works fine, but I would then need to clone them, move my template, commit and push. I was wondering if there is already a library for this case or if I would need to create one myself.

Thanks

Comment: Based on the link you referred, git repos can be created progrmmatically (`var createRepo = require( 'github-create-repo' );`). But you should manually add your template to each repo separately.